# Facebook page plug in not appearing in website

Tags: javascript, facebook, plugins

Try as I might, I can't get my Facebook group to appear on my website. I'm using the meta page plug in script generator, I paste in my URL, copy the code into my html file and... nothing. My website doesn't show anything. I've searched for a solution, checked restrictions, got a developer account, repasted the link, stripped out all my html apart from the plug in, nothing's working. I notice that when I paste my link into the meta page it doesn't generate a preview of the plug in, and I've seen you tube videos showing that happening. I can view the Facebook group in a private browsing window, so it's not that either. I've cleared my browsers cache and tried edge, firefox and chrome. Nothing helps.

Anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you are really talking about a Facebook _group_, then it is no wonder that this does not work - the plugin is for _pages_, not groups. Totally different things.